# The best way to create a clickable progressbar with a text

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button, android-progressbar

I need to implement a thick clickable progress-bar with rounded corners and text in it.

What is the best - meant easiest - way to implement it? I found a couple of topics here on progressbar with rounded corners, but I need something beyond it...

Should I extend a Button, a ProgressBar or a TextView?

TIA

Comment: It's just a very bad UI design pattern. You could explain why you need to do this and maybe find a better alternative from UX perspective.